# What do I need to run VMware to the full extent?

Tags: windows-10, vmware-workstation

I have a core i7-6700HQ with 8GB Ram, GTX 960M (4GB) , a 1TB 5200RPM HDD - Lenovo IdeaPad Y700 and I have Windows 10 installed in it and I got myself a VMware Workstation as my teacher told me to work on a virtual Windows 10.  Even though I assigned 8 cores to the VM with 6GB ram the VM runs really slowly I can't get to know what the reason behind that would be!

So what do I need to upgrade my laptop to run the VM smoothly because as of right now I can't run it smoothly at all!

Comment: You should really talk to your teacher about that. First off, there's not such thing as "full extent", only "the best efficiency given a certain set of hardware and software". 2nd, you have a slow hard drive. 3rd, you gave most of your computer's RAM to the VM which means the host computer will be running even slower. 4th, any virtualization system will lose a small about over speed to the host system, and this is much worse on a desktop hypervisor like yours.

Comment: the VM already eats most of the real machine's RAM so all will run slowly. You don't need that much RAM for the VM. Choose wisely depending on your assignment

Comment: Aside from needing a lot more RAM before you can assign the VM 6GB, the optimum VM performance will be gained by assigning it the actual number of real cores you have; in your case 4. That will allow for the best 'sharing' between real OS & VM.

Comment: so can you please suggest me the best settings for my vm and the upgrades I need to make to my laptop

Comment: Did you install VMWare Tools?

Comment: Yes I did that already!

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled VT-x in your BIOS settings? This will allow your VMs to run faster, as enables them to be hardware accelerated.  Another thing you should do is to defragment your HDD if it's fragmented - it can improve the performance of the host computer as well as your VMs.

Also, I'd recommend that you open up Task Manager in the VM (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>) and see what your bottleneck is - it'll give you a better idea of why your VM is so slow. I've experienced that sometimes upon logon, disk usage in the VM will become quite high and slow it down. If I just leave it for a bit then it tends to settle and I can get on with whatever I need to do.

I too have a Y700, but with 16GB of RAM. I usually assign 2-4 CPUs and 2-4 GB of RAM to my VMs and they work fine. If you still want to upgrade then here are some options:

- Get 2x8GB of RAM to give 16GB
- Use the empty M.2 slot to fit an SSD (if you go for this, **don't** defrag it - you'll need to [TRIM](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/simple-questions-what-trim-ssds-why-it-useful) it instead)
- Replace the HDD with a SSHD

Comment: I did a quick search on Lenovo IdeaPad Y700.  Looks like it already comes with a SSD.  You *never* want to defrag a SSD.  However, +1 for stating that VT-x needs to be enabled.

Comment: I think it depends on the specific model as to what drive(s) the Y700 has got - when I was looking around to buy a laptop, some Y700s had just an SSD or HDD, and some had both. However, the OP did specify that he/she had an HDD, so the SSD defrag shouldn't be an issue, although I'll edit my post to include that warning!